# Tableau Percent Difference Between Week

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to display a graph that shows the increase or decrease in percentage of calls from each country over time (sample data and desired output below). This is intended to answer the question, "Has the proportion of calls within the USA compared to the others gone up or down in the past week?", *not* to be confused with answering the question if USA has just seen more calls.

In the example below, I am looking for a bar chart that shows increases/decreases for all of the countries (x-axis = country, y-axis = percent difference)

I understand how to do this based on a simple change in count, but am struggling to look at this as percent of the total.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to do a Table Calc on a table calc. No problems to do this. I suggest creating the first calculated field and saving it as a new calculation. Then use that field within your final table calculation.

If you're creating the table calculation using the Quick Table Calculation, double click in the pill to see the underlying formula - you can copy this out and paste into a new calculated field.

You are also able to set the "Compute Using" separately using this method, which may be useful in this example.